# Displaying lines from text file in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

File test.cmd:

```
name=dummy  

for /f "eol=; tokens=1 delims=," %%i in (list.txt) do (  
echo i: %%i  
set name=%%i  
echo name: %name%)
```

the file list.txt contains this lines (one name per line):

```
John  
Tom  
Erica  
Sara
```

---

Each time I launch this batch I get this output:

```
i: John  
name: dummy  
i:T om  
name: dummy  
i: Erica  
name: dummy  
i: Sara  
name: dummy
```

It seems that the variable name does not get assigned the value of `%%i`

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're falling into the old trap of not using delayed expansion.

For a quick fix, just put

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

before that loop in your batch file and use `!name!` instead of `%name%`.

CMD expands variables while parsing a command. A command in this sense is a single line or a “block”, delimited with parentheses. The complete `for` loop is only parsed once and in that stage `%name%` gets replaced with the value it has at that point, namely `"dummy"`. Delayed expansion on the other hand uses `!` instead of `%` to delimit variable names and the variables then get expanded right before execution of a command.

Whenever you are setting a variable inside a parenthesized block *and* use its value in the same block again you need to use delayed expansion. `help set` has also some info about this:

> Delayed environment variable expansion
>   is useful for getting around the
>   limitations of the current expansion
>   which happens when a line of text is
>   read, not when it is executed.  The
>   following example demonstrates the
>   problem with immediate variable
>   expansion:
>
> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
> ```
>
> would never display the message, since
>   the `%VAR%` in *both* `IF` statements is
>   substituted when the first `IF`
>   statement is read, since it logically
>   includes the body of the `IF`, which is
>   a compound statement.  So the `IF`
>   inside the compound statement is
>   really comparing “before” with “after”
>   which will never be equal.  Similarly,
>   the following example will not work as
>   expected:
>
> ```
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```
>
> in that it will *not* build up a list of
>   files in the current directory, but
>   instead will just set the `LIST`
>   variable to the last file found.
>   Again, this is because the `%LIST%` is
>   expanded just once when the `FOR`
>   statement is read, and at that time
>   the `LIST` variable is empty. So the
>   actual `FOR` loop we are executing is:
>
> ```
> for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i
> ```
>
> which just keeps setting `LIST` to the
>   last file found.
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion
>   allows you to use a different
>   character (the exclamation mark) to
>   expand environment variables at
>   execution time.  If delayed variable
>   expansion is enabled, the above
>   examples could be written as follows
>   to work as intended:
>
> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
>
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! You definitaly saverd my day.
fabio vitale